# Drupal Views Ajax Error very long

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I get this error in Drupal 6 Views 1.3 whenever I click any setting. Even on a brand new View. I deleted some CCk fields I wasn't using in phpmyadmin this may have something to do with it. I turned off Vies Ajax and cache.

Here is the error.

> An error occurred at
>   /drupal163/admin/build/views/ajax/add-item/view_rss_youtube/default/sort.
>
> Error Description: { "display": "\x3cform
>   action=\"/drupal163/admin/build/views/ajax/add-item/view_rss_youtube/default/sort\"
>   accept-charset=\"UTF-8\" method=\"post\"
>   id=\"views-ui-add-item-form\"\x3e\n\x3cdiv\x3e\x3cdiv
>   class=\"form-item\" id=\"edit-group-wrapper\"\x3e\n \x3clabel
>   for=\"edit-group\"\x3eGroups: \x3c/label\x3e\n \x3cselect
>   name=\"group\" class=\"form-select views-master-dependent\"
>   id=\"edit-group\" \x3e\x3coption value=\"all\"\x3e- All
>   -\x3c/option\x3e\x3coption value=\"comment\"\x3eComment\x3c/option\x3e\x3coption
>   value=\"content\"\x3eContent\x3c/option\x3e\x3coption
>   value=\"feeds-item\"\x3eFeeds item\x3c/option\x3e\x3coption
>   value=\"feeds-source\"\x3eFeeds source\x3c/option\x3e\x3coption
>   value=\"global\"\x3eGlobal\x3c/option\x3e\x3coption
>   value=\"node\"\x3eNode\x3c/option\x3e\x3coption
>   value=\"node-hierarchy\"\x3eNode Hierarchy\x3c/option\x3e\x3coption
>   value=\"node-revision\"\x3eNode revision\x3c/option\x3e\x3coption
>   value=\"taxonomy\"\x3eTaxonomy\x3c/option\x3e\x3coption
>   value=\"upload\"\x3eUpload\x3c/option\x3e\x3coption
>   value=\"user\"\x3eUser\x3c/option\x3e\x3c/select\x3e\n\x3c/div\x3e\n\x3cdiv class=\"views-radio-box form-checkboxes\"\x3e\x3cdiv
>   class=\"views-dependent-all views-dependent-comment\"\x3e\x3cdiv
>   class=\"form-item\" id=\"edit-name-comments.name-wrapper\"\x3e\n
>   \x3clabel class=\"option\"
>   for=\"edit-name-comments.name\"\x3e\x3cinput type=\"checkbox\"
>   name=\"name[comments.name]\" id=\"edit-name-comments.name\"
>   value=\"comments.name\" class=\"form-checkbox\" /\x3e Comment:
>   Author\x3c/label\x3e\n \x3cdiv class=\"description\"\x3eThe name of
>   the comment\'s author. Can be rendered as a link to the author\'s
>   homepage.\x3c/div\x3e\n\x3c/div\x3e\n\x3cdiv class=\"form-item\"
>   id=\"edit-name-comments.homepage-wrapper\"\x3e\n \x3clabel
>   class=\"option\" for=\"edit-name-comments.homepage\"\x3e\x3cinput
>   type=\"checkbox\" name=\"name[comments.homepage]\"
>   id=\"edit-name-comments.homepage\" value=\"comments.homepage\"
>   class=\"form-checkbox\" /\x3e Comment: Author\'s
>   website\x3c/label\x3e\n \x3cdiv class=\"description\"\x3eThe website
>   address of the comment\'s author. Can be rendered as a link. Will be
>   empty if the author is a registered
>   user.\x3c/div\x3e\n\x3c/div\x3e\n\x3cdiv class=\"form-item\"
>   id=\"edit-name-comments.hostname-wrapper\"\x3e\n \x3clabel
>   class=\"option\" for=\"edit-name-comments.hostname\"\x3e\x3cinput
>   type=\"checkbox\" name=\"name[comments.hostname]\"
>   id=\"edit-name-comments.hostname\" value=\"comments.hostname\"
>   class=\"form-checkbox\" /\x3e Comment: Hostname\x3c/label\x3e\n
>   \x3cdiv class=\"description\"\x3eHostname of user that posted the
>   comment.\x3c/div\x3e\n\x3c/div\x3e\n\x3cdiv class=\"form-item\"
>   id=\"edit-name-comments.cid-wrapper\"\x3e\n \x3clabel class=\"option\"
>   for=\"edit-name-comments.cid\"\x3e\x3cinput type=\"checkbox\"
>   name=\"name[comments.cid]\" id=\"edit-name-comments.cid\"
>   value=\"comments.cid\" class=\"form-checkbox\" /\x3e Comment:
>   ID\x3c/label\x3e\n \x3cdiv class=\"description\"\x3eThe comment ID of
>   the field\x3c/div\x3e\n\x3c/div\x3e\n\x3cdiv class=\"form-item\"
>   id=\"edit-name-comments.status-wrapper\"\x3e\n \x3clabel
>   class=\"option\" for=\"edit-name-comments.status\"\x3e\x3cinput
>   type=\"checkbox\" name=\"name[comments.status]\"
>   id=\"edit-name-comments.status\" value=\"comments.status\"
>   class=\"form-checkbox\" /\x3e Comment: In moderation\x3c/label\x3e\n
>   \x3cdiv class=\"description\"\x3eWhether or not the comment is
>   currently in the moderation queue.\x3c/div\x3e\n\x3c/div\x3e\n\x3cdiv
>   class=\"form-item\" id=\"edit-name-comments.mail-wrapper\"\x3e\n
>   \x3clabel class=\"option\"
>   for=\"edit-name-comments.mail\"\x3e\x3cinput type=\"checkbox\"
>   name=\"name[comments.mail]\" id=\"edit-name-comments.mail\"
>   value=\"comments.mail\" class=\"form-checkbox\" /\x3e Comment:
>   Mail\x3c/label\x3e\n \x3cdiv class=\"description\"\x3eEmail of user
>   that posted the comment. Will be empty if the author is a registered
>   user.\x3c/div\x3e\n\x3c/div\x3e\n\x3cdiv class=\"form-item\"
>   id=\"edit-name-comments.timestamp-wrapper\"\x3e\n \x3clabel
>   class=\"option\" for=\"edit-name-comments.timestamp\"\x3e\x3cinput
>   type=\"checkbox\" name=\"name[comments.timestamp]\"
>   id=\"edit-name-comments.timestamp\" value=\"comments.timestamp\"
>   class=\"form-checkbox\" /\x3e Comment: Post date\x3c/label\x3e\n
>   \x3cdiv class=\"description\"\x3eDate and time of when the comment was
>   posted.\x3c/div\x3e\n\x3c/div\x3e\n\x3cdiv class=\"form-item\"
>   id=\"edit-name-comments.thread-wrapper\"\x3e\n \x3clabel
>   class=\"option\" for=\"edit-name-comments.thread\"\x3e\x3cinput
>   type=\"checkbox\" name=\"name[comments.thread]\"
>   id=\"edit-name-comments.thread\" value=\"comments.thread\"
>   class=\"form-checkbox\" /\x3e Comment: Thread\x3c/label\x3e\n \x3cdiv
>   class=\"description\"\x3eSort by the threaded order. This will keep
>   child comments together with their
>   parents.\x3c/div\x3e\n\x3c/div\x3e\n\x3cdiv class=\"form-item\"
>   id=\"edit-name-comments.subject-wrapper\"\x3e\n \x3clabel
>   class=\"option\" for=\"edit-name-comments.subject\"\x3e\x3cinput
>   type=\"checkbox\" name=\"name[comments.subject]\"
>   id=\"edit-name-comments.subject\" value=\"comments.subject\"
>   class=\"form-checkbox\" /\x3e Comment: Title\x3c/label\x3e\n \x3cdiv
>   class=\"description\"\x3eThe title of the
>   comment.\x3c/div\x3e\n\x3c/div\x3e\n\x3c/div\x3e\x3cdiv
>   class=\"views-dependent-all views-dependent-content\"\x3e\x3cdiv
>   class=\"form-item\"
>   id=\"edit-name-node-data-field-embed-youtube.field-embed-youtube-embed-wrapper\"\x3e\n
>   \x3clabel class=\"option\"
>   for=\"edit-name-node-data-field-embed-youtube.field-embed-youtube-embed\"\x3e\x3cinput
>   type=\"checkbox\"
>   name=\"name[node_data_field_embed_youtube.field_embed_youtube_embed]\"
>   id=\"edit-name-node-data-field-embed-youtube.field-embed-youtube-embed\" value=\"node_data_field_embed_youtube.field_embed_youtube_embed\"
>   class=\"form-checkbox\" /\x3e Content: embed_youtube
>   (field_embed_youtube)\x3c/label\x3e\n \x3cdiv
>   class=\"description\"\x3eEmbedded Video - Appears in:
>   youtube_cck\x3c/div\x3e\n\x3c/div\x3e\n\x3cdiv class=\"form-item\"
>   id=\"edit-name-node-data-field-embed-youtube.field-embed-youtube-description-wrapper\"\x3e\n
>   \x3clabel class=\"option\"
>   for=\"edit-name-node-data-field-embed-youtube.field-embed-youtube-description\"\x3e\x3cinput
>   type=\"checkbox\"
>   name=\"name[node_data_field_embed_youtube.field_embed_youtube_description]\"
>   id=\"edit-name-node-data-field-embed-youtube.field-embed-youtube-description\"
>   value=\"node_data_field_embed_youtube.field_embed_youtube_description\"
>   class=\"form-checkbox\" /\x3e Content: embed_youtube
>   (field_embed_youtube) - Description\x3c/label\x3e\n \x3cdiv
>   class=\"description\"\x3eEmbedded Video - Appears in:
>   youtube_cck\x3c/div\x3e\n\x3c/div\x3e\n\x3cdiv class=\"form-item\"
>   id=\"edit-name-node-data-field-embed-youtube.field-embed-youtube-duration-wrapper\"\x3e\n \x3clabel class=\"option\"
>   for=\"edit-name-node-data-field-embed-youtube.field-embed-youtube-duration\"\x3e\x3cinput
>   type=\"checkbox\"
>   name=\"name[node_data_field_embed_youtube.field_embed_youtube_duration]\"
>   id=\"edit-name-node-data-field-embed-youtube.field-embed-youtube-duration\"
>   value=\"node_data_field_embed_youtube.field_embed_youtube_duration\"
>   class=\"form-checkbox\" /\x3e Content: embed_youtube
>   (field_embed_youtube) - Duration\x3c/label\x3e\n \x3cdiv
>   class=\"description\"\x3eEmbedded Video - Appears in:
>   youtube_cck\x3c/div\x3e\n\x3c/div\x3e\n\x3cdiv class=\"form-item\"
>   id=\"edit-name-node-data-field-embed-youtube.field-embed-youtube-provider-wrapper\"\x3e\n \x3clabel class=\"option\"
>   for=\"edit-name-node-data-field-embed-youtube.field-embed-youtube-provider\"\x3e\x3cinput
>   type=\"checkbox\"
>   name=\"name[node_data_field_embed_youtube.field_embed_youtube_provider]\"
>   id=\"edit-name-node-data-field-embed-youtube.field-embed-youtube-provider\"
>   value=\"node_data_field_embed_youtube.field_embed_youtube_provider\"
>   class=\"form-checkbox\" /\x3e Content: embed_youtube
>   (field_embed_youtube) - Provider\x3c/label\x3e\n \x3cdiv
>   class=\"description\"\x3eEmbedded Video - Appears in:
>   youtube_cck\x3c/div\x3e\n\x3c/div\x3e\n\x3cdiv class=\"form-item\"
>   id=\"edit-name-node-data-field-embed-youtube.field-embed-youtube-status-wrapper\"\x3e\n
>   \x3clabel class=\"option\"
>   for=\"edit-name-node-data-field-embed-youtube.field-embed-youtube-status\"\x3e\x3cinput
>   ty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe you have a conflict in jquery,
try this module [jquery_update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update)

Comment: Monty, You are right. I forgot to install the jquery_ui module and the jquery_update module. I ran update but I am still getting the views error.

Comment: I think it took awhile to take affect, I also saw on the status page a needed Image API GD. I enabled. ImageAPI, ImageAPI GD2,ImageCache UI. The views error is gone. Thank you.

Comment: Actually the views error came back. Its the theme that is causing it. Minnelli and Garland give me views errors but Bluemarine and Chameleon do not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with AJAX and VIEWS and I found the solution changing the jQuery version through [jquery_update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update).

It's was configured to use the latest version of jQuery, 1.8, and I changed it to 1.7. After that, AJAX and VIEWS worked again as usual.

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Go through the changes made on https://drupal.org/node/752290

It worked for me!

Also try these if it helps (these have helped others but not me)

[comment-1](https://drupal.org/node/326378#comment-2309534)

They don't allow me to post more than 2 links(repuation issues) so go through this (unformatted link, cut paste on browser)

drupal.org/node/752290#comment-3311950